# Visual Studio | Determine Template Type of an existing Project

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, project-template

I am trying to rebuild an existing solution from scratch.
I know that the main project is created from a ASP.NET web application template.

But I am stuck when I want to create another project for unit testing as there are a bunch of templates to choose from (MSTest, NUnit, xUnit, etc.)

From the project type GUIDs and this overview of [Visual Studio Project Type Guids](https://github.com/JamesW75/visual-studio-project-type-guid) I know that the project is of type

- **C#** (GUID: FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC) and
- **Test** (GUID: 3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB)

But this information does not help me in choosing the exact same template of the original project.

Is there any way to get information on the very template that was used for the original project?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Because you have project type GUIDs I assume this is a legacy style project, not an SDK style project. In VS2022 the template to use is probably "Unit Test Framework (.NET Framework)".

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you a lot for your answer. I was able to test the template "Unit Test Framework (.NET Framework)" and it seems like it's exactly what I was looking for. I am happy to accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have project type GUIDs I assume this is a legacy style project, not an SDK style project. In VS2022 the template to use is probably "Unit Test Framework (.NET Framework)".